# WebStorm JavaScript destructuring assignment

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, webstorm

The following valid ES6 in WebStorm:

```
let {a,b} = {a:0,b:0};
{a,b} = {a:2,b:4};
```

shows an error at the second equals sign: "expression expected". Obviously JavaScript settings are set to ES6.

By the way adding parentheses removes the error:

```
let {a,b} = {a:0,b:0};
({a,b} = {a:2,b:4});
```

Is this a bug or part of the ES6? The node compiler seems to have no problem with the first version (without the parentheses), so it doesn't seem to be part of the standard.

Comment: The first one is a syntax error, also in node. it would be `let {a,b}= {a:0,b:0}` or the second version.

Comment: @baao I think that it wouldn't be `let`, since the `a` and `b` variables will be global. Not even `var`. Just global variables.

Comment: why @Kinduser ?

Comment: @baao Simple test - `function x() { ({a,b} = {a:2,b:4}); }`. After calling this function you will be able to access these variables in global scope. If it would be `const`, `let` or even `var`, you wouldn't have access to it outside function.

Comment: True, but if you have it as the OP they are not. He declares both the variables with `let`, then overrides them. That doesn't make them global. @Kinduser

Comment: @baao If he really overwrites it, then it won't make it global indeed.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not sure about it... Your interpretation makes more sense than mine (and his code)... :-) @Kinduser

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a bug, this is how [`ExpressionStatement`](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#prod-ExpressionStatement) are:

> NOTE
>   An **ExpressionStatement cannot start with a U+007B (LEFT CURLY BRACKET)** because that might make it ambiguous with a Block. An ExpressionStatement cannot start with the function or class keywords because that would make it ambiguous with a FunctionDeclaration, a GeneratorDeclaration, or a ClassDeclaration. An ExpressionStatement cannot start with async function because that would make it ambiguous with an AsyncFunctionDeclaration. An ExpressionStatement cannot start with the two token sequence let [ because that would make it ambiguous with a let LexicalDeclaration whose first LexicalBinding was an ArrayBindingPattern.

Answer (score 0):

Put parens around your assignment.  For example, the following is correct

```
let foo
({foo = 3} = {foo: 2})
```